# Ubuntu 18.04 Server - GUI remote access

Tags: server, gnome, cron, 18.04, remote-desktop

I have installed new Ubuntu Server with GNOME GUI. I configured Remmina to remote desktop. It works fine. However, I need remote access enabled, without first having to log in locally on the box.

How can I enable graphical remote control, without first having to log in locally on the machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Comment: Nope, I wrote that I need set autostart remmina before fist log in. Your suggestion is after log in. This is server. I need set this service the same like ssh, whose start automatically after boot.

Comment: Remmina is a Rdp client? It doesn't make sense in my opinion to start this before login.

Comment: Tell this microsoft where remote desktop works after boot system and before first log in from many years. Serwer is in another location so when I restart it, how I can remote to this? I must go there, login first time and after then can remote from my office. Where is sense to go to another location after every restart? I can't start remmina even I connect via ssh on user, this will be another way to resolve my issue, but can't. So I start thinking about autostart remmina.

Comment: I rewrote your question based on your comment. Also note that the traditional management way is ssh.

Comment: I see, thanks! I know that ssh is, but I have some GUI apps to statistic and reports, so I need sometimes logged remotely. Not everything can't do via terminal.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used for x11vnc, this may help you with your problem with just switching out the program and names.

```
# Step 8 - Create the Service Unit File
# ################################################################# 

#cat > /lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service << EOF
#[Unit]
#Description=Start x11vnc at startup.
#After=multi-user.target

#[Service]
#Type=simple
#ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -shared

#[Install]
#WantedBy=multi-user.target
#EOF

# Step 9 -Configure the Service 
# ################################################################ 

#echo "Configure Services"
#sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service
#sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: Have you all instruction to configure x11vnc? Remmina is only option for me, I need remote desktop, it might be anything.

Comment: I was try to do this for remmina, but i don't know nothing about some switches for guest account on remmina.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the a line in `/etc/rc.local` which is the path to the program you want to run. So if the program/file/script is in `/etc` the line you will add would be like as following: 
`/etc/file name`
This worked for me with out a hitch so far.

Comment: I haven't `rc.local` in /etc on any my desktop or server. Only I have:  `rc0.d/ rc1.d/ rc2.d/ rc3.d/ rc4.d/ rc5.d/ rc6.d/ rcS.d/ `

Comment: @AxelGocan what about `/etc/init`? do you have that?

Comment: Yep, and in this: `anacron.conf  gpu-manager.conf  mysql.conf  whoopsie.conf`

Comment: okay then in `/etc/init` save in a `.conf` file with the following `start on startup` next line
`task` next line
`exec /path/to/command`

Comment: Nope, this isnt work. I was created `/etc/init/remmina.conf` and inside is `start on startup
task
exec /usr/bin/remmina` like you wrote, but after reboot still remmina don't start on server and I can't remote from my host.

Comment: well i have to dig a little more then. there is one last thing i recall and that is to check System > Preferences > Startup Applications with the GUI that should be a possible solution other wise more digging for me and you can check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: You can't start a gui app using init files. You have to configure your DE to autostart that app.

Comment: @delfiler Unfortunatlly the method from link works after login as user. And I have remmina there. I need start remmina before login the user. This will be server located in another building, so after some restarts I need logged for it remotely.

Comment: @vidarlo what you mean DE?